# I have an interface with 200+ properties. How can a class implement this interface without declaring all 200+ again?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, static-typing

I have an interface with 200+ properties and a class that uses these same properties.

```
interface MyProperties {
  property1: string
  property2: string
  ...
  property232: string
}

class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.property1 = 'foo';
    this.property2 = 'bar';
    ...
    this.property232 = 'bar';
  }
}
```

Right now typescript will give me this error: `Property 'property1' does not exist on type 'MyClass'.`

Is there a way to tell typescript that my class properties come from the `MyProperties` interface?

I **dont** want to do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  property1: string
  property2: string
  
  constructor() {
    this.property1 = 'foo';
    this.property2 = 'bar';
  }
}
```

since the interface is already used extensively in my code and I don't want to repeat these typings.

Closest I've come is this

```
class MyClass {
  property1: MyProperties['property1'];
  property2: MyProperties['property2'];
  ...
  property232: MyProperties['property232'];

  constructor() {
    this.property1 = 'foo';
    this.property2 = 'bar';
    ...
    this.property232 = 'bar';
  }
}
```

but it's not super pretty, since in my actual code I have 200+ properties

Comment: The two answers provided solve your problem, except you say they don't work for you because you have 200+ properties. Then you need to make the "200+ properties" front and center to your question, not as a tiny comment at the end. I'll move it to the top but you need to add more info.

Comment: For example, you need to provide more info about these 200+ properties: Are they all in the same interface? With so many properties, does static type checking even make sense? You have to provide values for all of them (unless they are optional) so you still have a "not super pretty" problem. If you provide details on your need rather than "make this code work", we can provide better solutions.

Comment: No, that's not how interfaces work in Typescript or ANY language that I know of. You don't inherit interfaces, you **implement** them, and "implement" means you have to do what you don't want to do.  You can change your interface into an abstract class and then use inheritance...   AND PLEASE answer my other questions, either here in comments or by updating your question (better).

Comment: @Inigo They're all in one interface and its a mix of all kinds of types.

For any other data type I can just do `const myObject: MyType = {}`. From the answers here I assume there is no equivalent for classes.

Comment: What is `MyType`?  You cannot do `const myObject: MyProperties = {}`. You cannot conform to a type without actually implementing all the non-optional fields of that type unless you use inheritance. Feel free to correct me with an example in Typescrtipt Playground, e.g. like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AKUD2AHaMYCAZ2QG8AoZZPXAqMdARgC5kSwpQBza2+oXQAmdp24g+AX0qyEOEJ2QBbdAHkARgCsICMOwzZ8hYmQC8FGZSA), and please put in in your question. You need to do more work with clarity, not us. My gut says you're confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well just add an `implements MyProperties` clause to the class:

```
interface MyProperties {
    property1: string
    property2: string
}

class MyClass implements MyProperties {
    property1: string;
    property2: string;

    constructor() {
        this.property1 = 'foo';
        this.property2 = 'bar';
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I still need to re-add all my types by hand to the class. I have an interface with 200+ methods, so I'd prefer not having to type all of those twice

Comment: If they're methods, surely you'll need to implement them yourself anyways? Maybe what you want is an abstract class?

Comment: I agree that you probably need an abstract class rather than an interface

Comment: A type with 200+ properties smells really fishy to me. I bet that if we knew about the underlying problem, we'd recommend something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now typescript will give me this error

Thats because there are no definition **in class** for this properties. You should tell TypeScript compiler that `MyClass` has this properties:

```
class MyClass {
    property1: string;
    property2: string;
    constructor() {
        this.property1 = 'foo';
        this.property2 = 'bar';
    }
}
```

Now, compiler know what properties `MyClass` has and can realize that `MyClass` implementing `MyProperties` interface:

```
interface MyProperties {
    property1: string
    property2: string
}

class MyClass {
    property1: string;
    property2: string;
    constructor() {
        this.property1 = 'foo';
        this.property2 = 'bar';
    }
}

const a: MyProperties = new MyClass(); // no error here
```

Also you can explicitly implement `MyProperties` interface to improve readability of code using `implements MyProperties`:

```
interface MyProperties {
    property1: string
    property2: string
}

class MyClass implements MyProperties {
    property1: string;
    property2: string;
    constructor() {
        this.property1 = 'foo';
        this.property2 = 'bar';
    }
}

const a: MyProperties = new MyClass(); // no error here too
```

Comment: but in this case I still have to type each property twice which is not ideal to maintain. I have 200+ properties in my class.